# how to have class return mock on new Class()?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

In phpunit, I want to test a controller. As part of this I need to return a mock when new Class() is called.

I have tried:

```
$mockEntity = $this->getMock( 'Vet', array( '__construct', 'setDoctrine', 'setContainer' ) );

$mockForm = $this->getMock( 'VetType', array( 'handleRequest', 'isValid', 'createView' ) );

$mockEntity->expects( $this->once() )->method( '__construct')->willReturn( $this->returnValue( $mockEntity ) );
```

and also simply:

```
$mockEntity = $this->getMock( 'Vet', array( 'setDoctrine', 'setContainer' ) );

$mockForm = $this->getMock( 'VetType', array( 'handleRequest', 'isValid', 'createView' ) );
```

Both return a "Vet" object, not the mock. Is this possible with phpUnit 4.0.20, or do I just need to add a getNewVet() function?

This is a Symfony2 controller

Comment: You instantiate (`new Class()`) the class in the controller? Why you don't define it as a service? Is more clean as code design (symfony2 best practice) and more easly to mock/test as dependency. Let me know if you need more help on this topic. Some reference [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: When you mock an object you mock a single instance of it. If you call the constructor of the class, you get a real object. Trying to mock the constructor of an object is nonsense, because the object is already constructed by the mocking framework.